# Maintain indexes directly in MongoDB and avoid the Rails app overwriting them

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, mongodb, mongoid

We have two Rails 5 apps that shares a clustered MongoDB, hosted on [mlab.com](https://mlab.com).

We define our fields/indexes through the models. The apps don't know about each others fields/indexes, and it needs to stay that way:

```
# app 1
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :order_number,            type: String
  belongs_to :status,             inverse_of: :orders
  index({ order_number: 1 },      { background: true })
  index({ status_id: 1 },         { background: true })
end

# app 2
class Order
  include Mongoid::Document
  field :order_number,            type: String
  field :internal_comment,        type: String
  index({ order_number: 1 },      { background: true })
  index({ internal_comment: 1 },  { background: true })
end
```

With only one app, we would simply maintain indexing with:

```
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:remove_indexes
bundle exec rake db:mongoid:create_indexes
```

But this would make each app cancel out each others indexing.

**Is it possible to create/remove indexes directly in MongoDB, and avoid the Rails apps overwriting it?**

---

To better understand the situation, consider the following series of events.

First, app 1 inserts new orders:

```
# app 1
Order.collection.insert_many(
  [
    {_id:             BSON::ObjectId('5b04208483c336a17ada564c'),
      order_number:   "1",
      status_id:      BSON::ObjectId('59db682c17be4a0005eb246a')
    },
    ...
  ]
)
```

Here we are facing problems with the indexing of `internal_comment`, because the index is not registered with both apps.

Next, app 2 queries for orders that has a `internal_comment`. It will be slow if indexing don't work properly:

```
# app 2
Order.collection.find(
  {
    internal_comment: { "$ne": nil }
  }
).to_a
```

Finally, app 2 updates one of the orders (that was inserted by app 1). I am not sure how that affects the indexing of the `status_id` and `internal_comment` fields.

```
# app 2 updates the order:
Order.collection.update_one(
  {
    _id:              BSON::ObjectId('5b04208483c336a17ada564c'),
    internal_comment: "foo"
  }
)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First of all, don't run `remove_indexes`. I haven't done that a single time in the 9 years I'm using mongodb and mongoid.

The indexes that you write into your model are only used for the `create_index` rake task and nowhere else (I could think of) and my own workflow is to create a new index through the mongo console, usually to figure out the best index variant (things like order of the components do matter after all) before adding it in the model for future reference. Read up on the [mongodb docs about createIndex](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/method/db.collection.createIndex/).